# How can I tell if video playback is ready after seek, with libVLC

Tags: c++, libvlc

I'm trying to tell the user that the seek operation has finished, and video playback can be started. But I'm unable to find a way to do this.

**libvlc_media_player_get_time** returns the correct time instantly after seek, my plan was to see when it changes to the current time, but no, this doesn't work.

**libvlc_media_player_will_play** seems to return true, regardless if playback can be started or not.

Any ideas?

I'm going to look if there's any way to get the PTS of the current frame.

Comment: What about waiting for a media_player_buffering event with a value of 100% complete? Not ideal but might work.

Comment: Didn't work, buffering might be something it does when it's connected to a stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My horrible hack, which does work, is the following.

```
void Video::setTime(int p_msecs)
{
   d->timeSet = p_msecs;
   libvlc_media_player_set_time(d->mediaPlayer, p_msecs);
}

bool Video::isSeekReady() const
{
    return d->timeSet != libvlc_media_player_get_time(d->mediaPlayer);
}
```

Comment: This can go quite bad as there are many variable frame rate videos where you cannot "guess" the correct timestamp of the next frame. So you request d->timeSet, but seeking will actually put you to the nearest frame (the timestamp associated with that frame) thus you might never reach d->timeSet

Comment: It might be true that this doesn't work with all videos even if I didn't yet encounter a video where this fails. I would be more worried that this depends on some internal logic which isn't documented anywhere and might change at any time. But it does work for some reason, even if I'm _NOT_ even attempting to "guess" a correct time. So it might even work with variable framerate videos, did you test it with one?